# K8s Nginx ingress controller setup for custom port

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have several PHP applications which I am trying to configure inside K8s.
Currently I have issue with one custom service - it is using own server (listening 8800 port) and nginx server which is redirecting traffic from 80/443 (we can use 80 this time to simplify example) to 8800.

Here is part of nginx conf:

```
location / {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_cache             off;

  proxy_pass              http://localhost:8800;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_redirect          off;
  proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
  proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;
}
```

I already configured deployments + services for my pods but I am new in NGINX Ingres.
Currently I am working with this ingress but I am getting 500 error (502 Bad Gateway) and looks like my traffic does not reach my service.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-[service]
  annotations:       
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: [my domain name]
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: [service]
            port:
              number: 8800
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

Did I convert nginx to ingres config correctly?

UPDATE: deployment + service (my last variant)

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: some-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: [some-name]
        image: [image]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        ...
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8800
            name: some-web-svc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: some-service-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8800
    targetPort: some-web-svc
    # - name: tcp
    #   port: 8800
    #   targetPort: 8800
  selector:
    app: some-service
```

Comment: The Ingress looks correct; I suggest sharing the Service and Deployment manifests. Meanwhile, to confirm the functioning of the Service+Deployment chain, check that it is possible to reach the application by pointing to the svc from a Pod of the cluster (example ```curl http://YOUR-APP-SVC-NAME.svc.cluster.local``` if you are in the same namespace).

Comment: @glv - updated post with deployment and service

Comment: I used internal IP address inside cluster and tried to telnet to my pod to 8800 from another and it was unreachable :( Looks like something wrong inside cluster

Comment: Is it to configure the *selector* in Deployment? That piece to check is missing in the code you shared (the part with the ... in the Deployment) ; https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/connect-applications-service/#exposing-pods-to-the-cluster

Comment: Please also share when you *exec* inside a Pod and run ```curl http://some-service.svc.cluster.local:8800```.

If the application responds, then the Pod/Service chain is OK.

Answer (score 1):

- Run the command below to check whether your service is mapped to your
  podIP:port properly.
- If the ENDPOINTS column in the output of the command below does not show podIP:port, then your service is most likely misconfigured - Label in the deployment is not matching with the selector in the service
- Fix the selectors to solve the issue

--

```
kubectl get ep -n <namespace>
```

Comment: `kubectl get ep` is showing me x.x.x.x:8800 but I cant telnet to this port. By the way, I can to kubernetes servuce - x.x.x.x:443. So, looks like something in my application config? I am able to telnet localhost 8800 inside pod but not outside..